# Casting void* to two-dimentional array

Tags: c, casting, multidimensional-array

I have a void* I am getting in some function which is actually a two-dimensional int array.
I want to send it as an argument to a function that expects a two dimensional array. 
What is the BEST way to cast it properly?

```
void foo(void* val){
   //How to cast val in order to send to bar??
   bar()
}

void bar(int val[2][2]){
//Do something 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `void *` translate itself automatically in C?

Comment: I cannot change the signature of bar!

Comment: @CarlNorum - just calling bar(val) will not compile

Comment: @Zahy: Have you tried it? It works in my compiler (GCC 4.6.1, C99 standard), and gives no warning even with all warnings turned on. Per the standard, I believe it *should* work in any C compiler (though not in a C++ compiler).

Comment: Yes. My mistake it does work(!) - responded too quickly.

Comment: +1 @ruakh - both clang and gcc with maximum warning settings (and even `-pedantic`) allow `bar(val)` without even a peep.

Answer (score 7):

```
bar((int(*)[2]) val);
```

(As Carl Norum states, the cast isn't even actually required; but it has the advantage of giving you a compiler warning if you accidentally pass it to a function expecting, say, a `int(*)[3]`.)

Comment: +1. It has the disadvantage of looking scary when it's really not.  Judgement call on the programmer's part, I guess, but I'd try to avoid writing something so crazy looking if possible.

Comment: @CarlNorum: I know what you mean. Personally, I try to avoid having multidimensional arrays end up as `void *`, when I can, since the round-trip is particularly error-prone. One alternative to using a multidimensional array is to wrap up the `int[2]` into a `struct`. Another is to use a jagged array, though obviously that means having to deal with memory allocation.

Comment: @CarlNorum and ruakh, thanks. Array casting is possible then, 
But why this does not work:?

int int2Arr[2][2] = (int(*)[2])theVoidPtr;

Comment: @Zahy: For the same reason that `int arr1[2][2]; int arr2[2][2] = arr1;` doesn't work. When an array is a parameter to a function, it's essentially just set up as a pointer to whatever is passed in; but when you declare an array as a local variable inside a function, the space for it is allocated on the stack, so it's not just a matter of reinterpreting an existing pointer.

Comment: @ruakh So if I have an argument which is declared as void* in the function signature BUT I know it is actually an int[2][2]  I have no choice but to copy it manually myself? Can't I cast it to int** and iterate on it?

Comment: @Zahy: If `p` is a `void *` that you know points to an `int[...][2]`, you can write `int (*arr)[2] = p;` to declare an `arr` that has the same underlying data, but has type `int[...][2]`. You can then refer to `arr[0][0]`, `arr[0][1]`, `arr[1][0]`, and `arr[1][1]`, just as you'd expect. You **cannot** cast it to an `int**`, because in C, a multidimensional array is *not* an array of pointers. Internally it's basically stored as a one-dimensional array, and the compiler does all the work to treat `arr[i][j]` as `((int *)p)[2*i+j]` (`2` being the number of elements per row).

Comment: @ruakh: int (*arr)[2] is actually a pointer to an array of size 2 of ints, right? So in my case, since its a two-dimensional array. Isn't the correct way is: int*(*arr)[2]=p
?

Comment: @Zahy: No, you need `int (*arr)[2]`. It's probably best not to overanalyze the notation, but if you really want to know . . . it's declaring a pointer to `int[2]`s, such that `arr[1]` means "the second `int[2]` and `arr[1][1]` means "the second element of the second `int[2]`".

Comment: @ruakh
So if I need int arr[2][7] then my cast should be: int(*arr)[7] ?

Comment: @Zahy: That's not a *cast*, that's a *declaration*. Something like `int arr1[2][7]; void * p = arr1; int (*arr2)[7] = (int (*)[7])p;` is valid, and makes `arr2[i][j]` be equivalent to `arr1[i][j]`. (If you want, you can even write `int (*const arr2)[7] = (int (*)[7])p;` to make it a bit more array-like: it will then be forbidden to change `arr2` to point somewhere else.)

Comment: @ruakh The last piece of this puzzle: I can't send my int** (nested) malloc'd array into a function with signature f(int a[2][7]) since it's actually just a pointer and cannot be "promoted" to two-dim array. Am I correct?

Comment: @Zahy: Right. `int**` could represent a jagged array, but in C, a true two-dimensional array is stored completely differently from a jagged array. There's no way to convert from the latter to the former (aside from copying all the data using nested loops).