# Incorrect numbers in square matrix using Assembler and C

Tags: c, assembly, matrix

I am trying to build a programm, that uses C code and Assembler file, that creates me a square matrix with random numbers, and after it places 1 on main and side diagonals.But I missed pointers, so my matrix convert from this

41 67 34 0 69

24 78 58 62 64

5 45 81 27 61

91 95 42 27 36

91 4 2 53 92

To this.
Edited matrix

1 1 1 1 1

1 0 -162768831 0 0

1 0 0 0 0

1 0 0 0 0

1 -162047930 0 0 0

I am using Visual Studio, Windows 10, and x64
This is my code on C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void fillMatrix(int n, int* matrix);

int main() {
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int n;

    printf("Введите размерность матрицы: ");
#pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int** matrix = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
    if (matrix == NULL) {
        printf("Ошибка выделения памяти.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        if (matrix[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Ошибка выделения памяти.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printf("Сгенерированная матрица до вызова функции на ассемблере:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    fillMatrix(n, matrix);
    printf("Сгенерированная матрица:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i * n + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my code on Assembler, where I miss the pointers, maybe because I use double pointers in C file(

```
.CODE
fillMatrix PROC

    mov     r8, rcx         
    mov     r9, rdx        

    xor     r10, r10        

fill_loop:
    cmp     r10, r8         
    jge     end_fill        

    mov     dword ptr [r9 + r10 * 8], 1   

    mov     r11, r10                      
    imul    r11, r8                 
    lea     r11, [r9 + r11 * 8]           
    mov     dword ptr [r11], 1            

    inc     r10            
    jmp     fill_loop      

end_fill:
    ret
fillMatrix ENDP
END
```

Comment: Didn't you post a similar question earlier today?

Comment: Please post code, data, **and results** as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Yes, you're not following the extra indirection. You're treating it as a row-major matrix, not an array of pointers.

Comment: Yeah, have your C create a proper 2D array, not this inefficient array-of-pointers stuff.  (Or a flat 1D array with manual 2D indexing; the asm doesn't care as long as the memory is contiguous and none of the allocated space is pointers).  [Casting void\* to two-dimentional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8288450) shows how to declare the function.  And [Malloc a 2D array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36890624) / [Create a pointer to two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1052818)